# Is radioactivity a property?

Tags: radioactivity

Radioactivity is the physical phenomena where an unstable atom decays and emits a radioactive particle. ***But is radioactivity a property, I.e. can an atom be radioactive or is it just unstable?*** Since radioactivity is a phenomena I would think you could say that atoms which are radioactive can create radioactivity but they are radioactive because they are unstable?

Comment: More a question of language usage than physics, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquially speaking, it's fine to say "that block of graphite over there is radioactive."

Speaking as a physicist, it's fine to say that carbon-14 is 'radioactive carbon' or a 'radioactive isotope of carbon.' In this sense, radioactivity is a property one could define as 'the property of having an excess of nuclear energy' or 'the property of having an unstable nuclus.'

Answer (score 0):

Not all elements are radioactive, and typically different isotopes of the same element have different radioactive characteristics.

> Is radioactivity a property?

What do you mean by a 'property'?  If you mean a consistent, measurable, predictable 'something' that is always related to that particular (isotope of the) element, then we would have to say that if an isotope of an element is radiactive then its radioactivity is definitely a property.  We understand how it can decay, and the rate at which it decays is understood and measurable.

> Is it radioactive or just unstable?

The process of radioactive decay means that the structure of the atom changes - either into another isotope of the same element or into a different element.  So we have to say that it must be unstable if it radioactive.